# What language is Raven using for her attack in the new 52?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, teen-titans

In the New 52 (*Teen Titans* #6, 2015) when Raven cast a spell, she uses some strange language, but I can't find out what this language means.

[image: Teen Titans fighting the villain, Raven casts a spell]

Comment: What is with the dialogue in this panel? Am I to understand that this is Raven, and she is casting a spell?

Comment: @RussellBorogove It really does appear to me that this is the case.  It's Raven, and, again, I say, it's Raven, and I say unto you a third time, It's Raven, and what I tell you three times, Mr. Borogrove, is true.  Further point--we also know that the fact of the spell is true, by the same logic (incl gobbletygook).  You have to wonder if the person that put this scene together has a sore inside his cheek from where he keeps his tongue.  It screams "hey guess what--the solution to the problem was Raven, and a spell!  I know *I'm* surprised, are you surprised?  We're all super surprised here."

Answer (score 234, accepted):

I don't think this is another language. The script doesn't look like any real writing system I've seen. It's more likely a custom magical-looking font, maybe disguising some English text. Usually four small words wouldn't be enough of a sample size to do any deciphering, but this panel gives us a clue: Someone on the far right points out (in case we couldn't figure it out?) that Raven is casting a *spell!*

The last word that Raven utters is five letters long, and all the letters are different, except for the last two. Just like the word *spell!* Let's see if this gets us anywhere.

If we assign arbitrary letters of our Roman alphabet to Raven's utterance, we can read it as:

```
ABCB DEFBG H GIBJJ
```

If we hypothesize that the last word is a cipher of "SPELL" then the whole thing looks like...

```
ABCB DEFBG H GIBJJ
 E E    ES   SPELL
```

If the single-letter word is English, it must be "I" or "A." And "I" doesn't really make sense in this context...

```
ABCB DEFBG H GIBJJ
 E E    ES A SPELL
```

This is actually looking really good. The "ES" at the end of the second word indicates a verb in a place where we'd expect a verb. The first word "_E_E" could be a lot of things, though. Let's see...

I used [Nutrimatic](https://nutrimatic.org/) to remind me of the most common English words that [match that pattern](https://nutrimatic.org/?q=AeAe&go=Go). The second result is "here."

```
ABCB DEFBG H GIBJJ
HERE    ES A SPELL
```

And this matches a common English formation, yielding something that totally matches what Raven is doing in this context:

```
ABCB DEFBG H GIBJJ
HERE COMES A SPELL !!
```

Further evidence for this interpretation: The "S" glyph looks like an S. The "C" glyph looks like a C. The "P" glyph looks like an upside-down P!

---

After all that cryptographic analysis, @Moyli supplied some far more conclusive evidence by discovering the actual font used, "Gobbledygook," which you can test out [here](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/comicraft/gobbledygook/bold-italic/) and confirm that the actual letters on the page are indeed *"here comes a spell!!"*

Comment: Wow, this is an impressive answer!

Comment: This is a you-win-the-Internet caliber answer.

Comment: Wow... really thanks a lot

Comment: … or it could be "WERE JONES A SHELL!!"

Comment: It's a shame it's not 1940, you might have got a nice letter from Bletchley Park.

Comment: Confirmed: the font is called Gobbledygook and if you type "here comes a spell" on [this page](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/comicraft/gobbledygook/bold-italic/) you can see it matches what's on the comic.

Comment: @Moyli: Nice job identifying the font itself!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite this simple substitution cipher is too simple even for 1940s.

Comment: @Moyli Note, lower case is required; upper case is far less subtle.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill This would be a standard calibre answer on [puzzling.se] SE. Check out that site if you want to be even more impressed :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I disagree. The answer gets going by making a pretty big guess, which would make for a poor puzzle if necessary, and a sub-optimal answer if not. On top of that, on puzzling there's the precondition that the puzzle should be solvable, which wasn't the case here at all.

Comment: I love this explanation, but I can't help feeling like you already knew what it said and then aimed to explain how one would go about solving it!

Comment: @Bee I had a bunch of it worked put in my head before I began composing my answer. I thought it would be more helpful to recreate my thought process—sorry if it comes off as a fabrication!

Comment: Was not a criticism at all! I love this answer

Comment: This is the rightest wrong answer I've ever read

Answer (score 0):

I believe the made up font is just meant to indicate that she is speaking words in an actual language (not just gibberish), but its not words in a language you the reader, or anyone else present at the time, actually knows.

Comment: I love what the other answer took from that and ran with, but I think its likely reading way more into it than intended.

Comment: _"Reading way more into it than intended"_ - [apparently not](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216683/what-language-is-raven-using-for-her-attack-in-the-new-52/216739#comment592411_216685)

Comment: In-universe, this is probably the correct explanation. I doubt the writer's intent was that the other Titans are actually hearing Raven say "HERE COMES A SPELL."

Comment: @Jenayah - You have to admit I was correct that it wasn't gibberish though...its Gobbledygook! :-)